# request post with body passed by paramter does not work

Tags: cypress

I hope someone will be able to help me.

This code works fine :

```
cy.request({
      method: 'POST', 
      url: surl, 
      log : true,
      auth: {
        user: 'xxxx',
        pass: 'xxxx'
      },
      headers: {
        //'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
      body:{
        Obpos_Applications_ID: 'AE765712BBCC47669475A5478EEFA8B3',
        inpKeyName: 'inpobposApplicationsId',
        inpTabId: 'FF80818132F311740132F3233778004B',
        inpTableId: 'FF80818132F311740132F31E2C9A0016',
        inpadClientId: '48429219C6DA47AEB1F7958F1375D601',
        inpadOrgId: '736B1011B45D4B96B31E329A15DB437A',
        inpcBpartnerId: '6A7F4BF891884403A48E1DC0921FA71B',
        inpcurrentCacheSessionId: '7139E00CEB614C6C947511AFCC6C20C5',
        inpdefaultwebpostab: 'scan',
        inpdocumentnoPadding: '7',
        inpemAc3Host: null,
        inpemAc3Interface: '',
        inpemAc3Port: null,
        inpemAc3Printsinfo: 'Y',
        inpemAc3Terminal: null,
        inpemGcnvGcseqLastnum: '0',
        inpemGcnvGcseqPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpemObcfrIsblockchained: 'N',
        inpemObposcsCopyTerminal: 'N',
        inpemPossBusinessdate: '27-11-2020',
        inpemPossClosesession: 'N',
        inpemPossOpensession: 'N',
        inpemPossSession: 'N',
        inpemPossStoreopen: null,
        inpfullinvdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpfullinvlastassignednum: '0',
        inpfullretinvdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpfullretinvlastassignednum: '0',
        inphardwareurl: 'http://localhost:8090/printer',
        inpisactive: 'Y',
        inpislinked: 'Y',
        inpismaster: 'N',
        inpkeyColumnId: 'Obpos_Applications_ID',
        inplastassignednum: '369',
        inpmasterterminalId: null,
        inpname: 'CAISSE_37_99_Automate',
        inpobposApplicationsId: 'AE765712BBCC47669475A5478EEFA8B3',
        inpobposCBpartnerLocId: '9AE0222DE3AD46498CFBB360DD1ADAD4',
        inpobposTerminaltypeId: 'B5AC8D0ED0654B89AAC1A299AD40B269',
        inpopenhardwareurl: 'N',
        inporderdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpprintertype: 'HWM',
        inpprintoffline: 'N',
        inpquotationdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpquotationslastassignednum: '0',
        inpreturndocnoPrefix: '37_99R',
        inpreturnslastassignednum: '1',
        inpscaleurl: null,
        inpsimpinvdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99SINV',
        inpsimpinvlastassignednum: '0',
        inpsimpretinvdocnoPrefix: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpsimpretinvlastassignednum: '0',
        inpterminalKeyId: 'CAISSE_37_99',
        inpterminalLastbenchmark: null,
        inpterminalLastcachegeneration: '26-11-2020 15:46:11',
        inpterminalLastcashupcompleted: '17-03-2021 13:55:05',
        inpterminalLastfullrefresh: null,
        inpterminalLasthwmjavainfo: 'Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)',
        inpterminalLasthwmrevision: '58d64521ad1b',
        inpterminalLasthwmversion: '1.0.5600',
        inpterminalLastincrefresh: null,
        inpterminalLastjsgeneration: null,
        inpterminalLastlogindate: null,
        inpterminalLastloginuser: 'B728314713644F8EBD2F6E80507D8E94',
        inpterminalLastordersynchronized: null,
        inpterminalLastticketloaded: null,
        inpterminalLasttimeinoffline: '16-10-2020 09:21:45',
        inpterminalLasttimeinonline: null,
        inpunlinkdevice: 'N',
        inpvalue: '990037',
        inpwindowId: 'FF80818132F311740132F322B8CD0048',
        keyColumnName: 'Obpos_Applications_ID',
        keyProperty: 'id',
        keyPropertyType: '_id_13',
        _buttonValue: 'DONE',
        _params: {}
      }
    })
    .then((responseactions) => {
      expect(responseactions.status).to.eq(200)   
      cy.log(responseactions.body)
    });
```

but if i use a parameter, it is ko.

```
cy.request({
      method: 'POST', 
      url: surl, 
      log : true,
      auth: {
        user: 'xxxx',
        pass: 'xxxx'
      },
      headers: {
        //'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
      body:{
        sbody
      }
    })
    .then((responseactions) => {
      expect(responseactions.status).to.eq(200)   
      cy.log(responseactions.body)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that `sbody` is

```js
const sbody = {
  Obpos_Applications_ID: 'AE765712BBCC47669475A5478EEFA8B3',
  inpKeyName: 'inpobposApplicationsId',
  ...
}
```

If so you want

```js
cy.request({
  method: 'POST', 
  url: surl, 
  log : true,
  auth: {
    user: 'xxxx',
    pass: 'xxxx'
  },
  headers: {
    //'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  },
  body: sbody
})
.then((responseactions) => {
  expect(responseactions.status).to.eq(200)   
  cy.log(responseactions.body)
});
```